# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ejs.ras.hpel.HpelHelper While Running jUnit

Tags: java, junit

I just finished writing a jUnit test. When I run it, everything seems to be OK, until it reaches a method call where I pass a DBConnection and then it throws the following error.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ejs.ras.hpel.HpelHelper

I've seen elsewhere that this could be a dependency issue, but nothing I've tried thus far has gotten me anywhere.

Comment: Hi, this error is usually caused because the JVM cannot find some class because there is an error in the hierarchy of the classes or because an unreachable dependency. Can you post more details about how are you writing your test and the package structure of the classes you are initializing?

Comment: updated above with some minor sample code

Answer (score 0):

It would appear in this circumstance, our DB does not allow write access from jUnit. So when a mocked connection attempts to access the DB it errors out. It's not an answer that would apply to anyone else I guess.